# What do we mean when we write the below code?

Tags: apex

```
for(AggregateResult a: results){
  //getting the AccountId and sum(Amount) in separate variables and putting it to map
  Id accountId = (Id)a.get('AccountId');
  double TotalAmount = (double)a.get('TotalAmount');
  amountMap.put(accountId,TotalAmount);
}
```

Comment: Please take our [tour], review [ask], and check out [help/on-topic]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some aggregate query on which is returning the Accountid, Amount .. etc. You are iterating the result through the for Loop  and adding the Id and Amount to the Map called amountMap. The same has been added in the comment as well in the code itself